# How to get sub-nested child element in LINQ Query

Tags: sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have Question and QuestionHierarchy Entity. The understanding is question can have many child questions, further each child question can have many sub-child questions, schema as following;

[image]

now I have managed to get child questions up to level 1, but wondering what is best way to get further nested child questions.

The requirement is to complete result in one sql script cycle to database, I am using Entity Framework core

### LINQ query

```
from question in Questions
where question.IsSubQuestion == false
select new { 
        question,  
        subQuestion = (from subQuestion in Questions
                      join questionHierarchy in QuestionHierarchies on subQuestion.Id  equals questionHierarchy.ChildQuestionId
                      where questionHierarchy.ParentQuestionId == question.Id 
                      group subQuestion by questionHierarchy.ParentQuestionId into GroupedItem
                      select new { 
                                      GroupedItem
                                  }
                         )  
        }
```

### Question Entity

```
 public class QuestionDataModel : IDataModel<Guid>
{
    public QuestionDataModel()
    {
        ChildQuestionsInHierarchy = new HashSet<QuestionHierarchyDataModel>();
    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionHierarchyDataModel> ChildQuestionsInHierarchy { get; set; }

   }
```

### Question Hierarchy

```
public class QuestionHierarchyDataModel 
{
    public QuestionHierarchyDataModel()
    {

    }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentQuestionId { get; set; }
    public Guid ChildQuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionDataModel ChildQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: *"The requirement is to complete result in one sql script cycle to database"* Then EF Core is definitely for you. In the best case it will execute 2 sql queries, in the worst case - N + 1.

Comment: that is fine but how to get further nested child questions, I have upto level 1,

Comment: Ah, you mean recursive query. It's not possible in LINQ at all. Use EF Core `Include` to load the whole graph in memory and then take the root elements. e.g. `db.Questions.Include(q => ChildQuestionsInHierarchy).AsEnumerable().Where(q => !q.IsSubQuestion)`

Comment: @IvanStoev Did you mean "not for you"?

Comment: @NetMage Good catch, thank you, that's exactly what I meant.